# Python range and list - what's the reason of this output?

Tags: list, range

I am self-learning, and not sure if this is a duplicate questions. In the example below:

Why does first list(a)==a print nothing?

Also why does a become false? And then turning back to a range object?

```
>>> a=range(10,17)
>>> list(a)==a
>>> list(a)==a
False
>>> a
False
>>> a
range(10, 17)
>>>
```

Moreover, if I call A once, then call list(A)==A. It always gives range(10, 17). Could anyone also explain this?

```
>>> A=range(10,17)
>>> A
>>> list(A)==A
range(10, 17)
>>>
```

Sorry for the rookie questions, I must miss some very basic logic here. Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: Maybe try running this again. I am not getting the same result as you. I think you may have accidentally reassigned `a` to the result of the comparison.

Comment: Your interactive session output seems impossible. Please show the exact, actual output from the interactive sessions. Why should `list(a) == a`? One is a list, one is a range, so they're trivially nonequal.

Comment: @Aposhian It seems the result is always printed one step late. This is so strange. Thank you for the comments.

Comment: What platform are you running your interactive session on? Is this in a web-based environment?

Comment: @Aposhian On my desktop. I restart Spyder and now the results are shown as expected. I am switching from R, and have never tried to fixed a issue with restart. Sorry for the confusion. I will delete the question if possible.